# How to migrate cordova project to visual studio 2017

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017

When i open an cordova project have run on vs2015 in vs2017,

it cannot normally build.

How to make it build normally?

Comment: Add the windows platform to a cordova project. Open the platforms folder -> Open windows folder -> You will find the VS compatible projects in this folder.